# LINQ to SQL Joining Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables, one for jobs, and one for the names of industries (e.g. automotive, IT, etc).

In SQL I would just do:

```
SELECT industryName, count(*)
FROM jobs
JOIN industry
ON jobs.industryId = industry.id
GROUP BY industryName
```

In LINQ I have the following, but it's three separate statements and I'm pretty sure this would be doable in one.

```
var allIndustries =
    from j in dbConnection.jobs
    join i in dbConnection.industries on j.industryId equals i.id
    select i.industryName;
var industriesWithCount =
    from i in allIndustries
    group i by i into iGrouped
    select new { Industry = iGrouped.Key, Count = iGrouped.Count() };
var industries = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var ic in industriesWithCount)
{
    industries.Add(ic.Industry, ic.Count);
}
```

Is there a way to make this simpler or shorter?

Comment: R u using Entity Framework to Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 8):

Your `j` and `i` variables are pretty plain and won't make this code fun to maintain (especially if it were a big block of code)

You should use more descriptive variables.

you should create a collection that groups the Jobs by their Industry and then select from that collection the industry name and the count of jobs in the collection with that name.

```
from job in dbConnection.jobs
join industry in dbConnection.industries on job.industryId equals industry.id
group new {industry, job} by industry.Name
into jobsByIndustry

select new {
    industryName = jobsByIndustry.Key.Name,
    jobscount = jobsByIndustry.Count()
}
```